# eclipse adt don't have android plugin update

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

i downloaded the eclipse adt for windows from here - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

for some reason i don't see the android icon for update under the "window". 
i did the update manually by install the "SDK Manager.exe", and also did the necessary update from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ for all of the developer tools, but i still can see this icon and don't see the android options at eclipse.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I too have installed eclipse and ADT from the same link which you have used. To update your eclipse, you will have to go to "Help">"Check for Updates". I hope this will help you if you want to update eclipse. Maybe, the new eclipse has that icon removed!